# Move cursor to matching goto/jump/label

Tags: delimiter-matching, plugin-treesitter, plugin-matchit

`Goto`/`label` statement pairs are available in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto), [Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/goto-statement), [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751207/how-can-i-use-goto-in-javascript), [Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899587/fortran-goto-scope), and other languages, too.

The unique word or number allows `goto` to find the associated `label`. How can I help vim recognize those associations, too, and use <kbd>%</kbd> to jump from a `goto` to the matching `label` and vice-versa?

I installed [matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup/) (similar to matchit) to allow using <kbd>%</kbd> to cycle through multi-part if-elif-elif-else-endif statements; ideally gotoA-gotoA-gotoA-labelA would also have the same behavior.

I have tried adding this with matchup for FANUC TP language, but it only highlights previous matches when I select the final LBL. It will not find the final label when I select initial JMP LBL statements. I have not found any working reference examples for any language.

Matchit code:

```
let b:match_words = '\<IF\>.*:\<ELSE\>.*:\<ENDIF\>.*,'
\ . '\<FOR\>.*:\<ENDFOR\>.*,'
\ . 'LBL\[\(\d\+\):LBL\[\1'
```

Sample FANUC TP code where the matches only work partially, with jump/labels highlighted. Note in this case, both JMP and WAIT can be goto statements; but as long as all the LBL[xx] are correlated, that is good enough for `%` motion.

```
LBL[11:Main process] ;
WAIT (DI[1105:SIGNAL END]=ON) TIMEOUT,LBL[91] ;
WAIT (DI[1106:SIGNAL START]=OFF) TIMEOUT,LBL[91] ;
LBL[12] ;
IF (DI[1118:RESULT GOOD]),JMP LBL[19] ;
WAIT (DI[1114:PARTIAL POSITION]) TIMEOUT,LBL[92] ;
WAIT (DI[1113:HOME POSITION]) TIMEOUT,LBL[93] ;
LBL[19:END PROCESS] ;
END ;
LBL[91:ERROR0] ;
LBL[92:ERROR1] ;
JMP LBL[11] ;
LBL[93:ERROR2] ;
JMP LBL[12] ;
```